# No write permission to Music Directory on Galaxy?

Tags: android, galaxy

I want save some audio files to the music directory, so other application can play it. I get the path using below codes:

```
dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

but the problem is that my apk doesn't have the write permission on it. And I observed that all the files ware in the Samsung sub-directory under the path returned by `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`.

Then i want filter the sub-directories using the creation time, but it is un-available under android.

So does anyone knows how to get the right directory? Or any other solutions?

Comment: If I remember well you are no longer can save files to external memory from any application, only to the internal memory. [you can see this here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) "...If your app needs to read the external storage (but not write to it)..."

Comment: The pre-defined public directory should be readable for application. I fixed it. If that directory is not writable, i will use the directory for downloading.